# ffmpeg remove 1 of 2 audio tracks without video reencode

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm trying to get rid of the 1st of two audio tracks in an mp4 file. But each time I run:

```
ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -map 0:0 -map 0:2 -acodec copy -vcodec copy new_file.mp4
```

ffmpeg seems to reencode the file.
The output says:

```
Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'test.mp4':
  Duration: 01:01:37.25, start: 0.-83411, bitrate: 4086 kb/s
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
    Stream #0.1(deu): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16
    Stream #0.2(eng): Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16
    Stream #0.3(und): Subtitle: text / 0x74786574
File 'new_file2.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Output #0, mp4, to 'new_file2.mp4':
    Stream #0.0(und): Video: 0x0000, yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 90k tbn, 90k tbc
    Stream #0.1(eng): Audio: 0x0000, 48000 Hz, 5.1, s16
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
  Stream #0.2 -> #0.1
Press [q] to stop encoding
frame=33700 fps=944 q=-1.0 size=  583098kB time=1405.53 bitrate=3398.5kbits/s
```

And this process takes quite some time, that's why I think it reencodes instead of copying. 
Any idea why this is? Maybe the different frame rate between container and codec?
Thanks!

Comment: Upgrade ffmpeg first. Your version is at least 7 years old.

Comment: Will try, I’m running on a PowerPC architecture tho.

Answer (score 1):

The first line of the output you provided explains the problem:

> ```
> Seems stream 0 codec frame rate differs from container frame rate: 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
> ```

and then the last three values in the 4<sup>th</sup> line tell about it in detail:

> ```
>     Stream #0.0(und): Video: h264, yuv420p, 1280x720, 23.98 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc
> ```

which mean, in words:

- I guess the frame rate `23.98` fps from the input video stream.
- The time base in the input container is set to `(1/90000)` seconds.
- The time base in its video stream is set to `(1/180000)` seconds.

Now, return to the the first line of your output, after the semicolon:

> ```
> 180000.00 (180000/1) -> 23.98 (24000/1001)
> ```

It means: *Your stream's framerate is 180,000 frames per second, but I will convert it to 23.98 fps.*

The same is in the mentioned 4<sup>th</sup> line, in the form `23.98 tbr`. It's the FFmpeg's guessed value.

So you are right, *the conversion occurs,* for both selected streams (video and audio one). You may see it from other lines of your output:

> ```
> Stream mapping:
>   Stream #0.0 -> #0.0
>   Stream #0.2 -> #0.1
> Press [q] to stop encoding
> ```

because in the case of *copying* them it would be as these:

> ```
> Stream mapping:
>   Stream #0.0 -> #0.0 (copy)
>   Stream #0.2 -> #0.1 (copy)
> Press [q] to stop
> ```

**The conclusion:**

Your command is correct, but your input file is damaged.

You may convince yourself about it by applying the same command to other, correct input file.